# Service for recording (camera or screenrecord) directly in browser

Tags: javascript, video, browser, streaming, wowza

I'm creating a service and want to implement a way for the users to easily record a video and upload it directly in the browser. I've looked into [Wowza](http://www.wowza.com) and [red5](http://www.red5.org). It would probably be easiest if the video would go straight to their server for perfomance. Does anyone have any experience with either one of them, or even more so, have any other alternatives that would work? I'm building the site in Django, but I'm somewhat afraid of hosting the whole service on my own service considering the performance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) article. It explains how to capture audio and video with HTML5 only. However, the browser support for this is horrible. The best and easiest way in my opinion is to make a own app with AS3 and PHP. It's fairly easy to do and gives you the best options for customization.

Answer (score 0):

Building such app in AS3 (Flash) and using Wowza as a backend is simple enough.
I personally participated in such projects.